# podman-py: arguments to run a container to join a network namespace

Tags: podman

With reference to https://github.com/containers/podman-py/blob/main/podman/domain/containers_create.py

I’d like to check what’s the correct arguments to supply to containers.run() or containers.create() to get the same effect as

`podman run --net ns:/run/netns/ns1 ...`

I have created a new network namespace with ip netns add ns1 and I'd like to create a new container using the Podman API to join this namespace. I successfully joined the name space on the command line with podman run -- net ns:/run/netns/ns1 but am not successful with the Python API client.

I tried `network_mode=ns:/run/netns/ns1` but got an error `Invalid network ns:/run/netns/ns1` instead. The documentation is not clear on this specific use case.